# Trying to make box that i can move if i click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make jquery script that allows me to move square according to my mouse movement if i click on it.Basicly it does nothing if i click on the box.it doesn't move the box after clicked and i have no idea why, can anyone help me..

```js
$(function(){
  var clicked=1;
  var ch,x,y,cy,cx;
  $('#box').on("click",function(){
    clicked=clicked+1;
    var ch=clicked%2;
    alert('ch'+ch);
  });
  alert('ifas');
  $('body').mousemove(function(){
    if(ch==0)
    {
      var x=event.pageX;
      var y=event.pageY;
      var cx=('#box').css("left");
      var cy=('#box').css("top");
      if(cx==='auto')
      {
        var cx=0;
      }else{
        var cx=cx.replace('px','')
        }
      if(cy==='auto')
      {
        var cy=0;
      }else{
        var cy=cy.replace('px','')
        }
      var cy=y-cy;
      var cx=x-cx;
      $('#box').css({
        top:cy,
        left:cx,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

css is basicly 100x100 box.
    https://jsfiddle.net/pL72en07/8/

Comment: Is there a question ? The "stupid form" is here to prevent users from posting stupid questions that aren't really questions. But it's not enough, obviously.

Comment: @Augustinas We need to know *specifically* what about it doesn't work. Does it not do anything? Does it only do one part of what you want? We can't know everything you want this to do without you putting it in your question.

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net also that people can see the css and fork your code. If there is no positioning code wouldn't be expected to work as is

Comment: Updated,sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problems are :

Missing `$` in :

```
var cx=$('#box').css("left");
       ^ // missing
var cy=$('#box').css("top");
       ^
```

Setting local `var` for `ch` in first click handler. This means the higher level `ch` is never defined and never changes

```
 $('#box').on("click",function(){
    clicked=clicked+1;
    ch=clicked%2; // remove `var`
    alert('ch'+ch);
  });
```

The box now moves although not smoothly and I don't know what your expectations are.

Comment: Thank you soo much :D,yes i was just needed that i am taking baby steps in learning jquery :)

Comment: Use your browser console to look for errors. The missing `$` was easy to spot there

Comment: Can not believe i did not see it,sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a element with the cursor when the mouse is pressed and release it at mouse position with another mouse press you can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
// Set the position attribute for the CSS style to absolute 
<div class="moveAble" style="position:absolute;">
    This div is movable!
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Wait for the dom to be ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    // declare variable for the element
    var moveable = $('.moveAble'),
        // variables for x,y position
        x,y,
        // bool that indicates wether the element should move or not.
        isMoving = false;

    // When the element is clicked
    moveable.on('click', function() {
        // Set the bool to be not the value it currently is, making it a toggle
        isMoving = !isMoving;
        // Use mousemove method and capture the event (e)
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            // set the x and y variables
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            // if isMoving is true, alter its top and left CSS attributes to the x and y coordinates for top and left
            if (isMoving) {
                moveable.css({'top': y,'left': x});
            }
        });
    });
});
```